# request.GET.get fails in IIS

Tags: django, iis

I'm having an issue with a Django application on IIS 8.5 running wfastcgi 2.1. When I test my app locally, everything works fine. When I move it to the IIS server, any python call to request.GET.get() returns none.

For example, I've a jquery autocomplete that uses my django view to get the objects to display in the autocomplete. I get the variable from the request.GET like so:

```
name = request.GET.get('name_startsWith')
```

I've also tried the old way

```
name = request.REQUEST.get('name_startsWith')
```

to no avail.

This works perfectly locally, but is None when running under IIS. Any ideas what might be going on or how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: According to Django documentation it’s strongly suggested that you use GET and POST instead of REQUEST, because the former are more explicit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried that as well. request.GET.get() also gives me None for the value. Editing to clarify.

Comment: Are you able to see the content of the request? Can you confirm that this key exist in your request? If it's not in the request maybe you have some error on your client side

Comment: I have the impression that you are using jQuery GET request on every keypress... Is this your case?

Comment: I can see the content of the request when running locally, and the key does exist. I am using the jQuery GET on every keypress, starting with the 3rd keypress. Again, no problems running locally with that approach, only on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! It turns out my IIS rewrite rule had appendQueryString='false', for some reason. Once I set that to true, all of a sudden everything started working properly.